# SQL Server performs dramatically after upgrading software

Tags: sql-server-2016

I’m new to this but I’m desperately hoping for a breakthrough. I’m a Support specialist that works for a company that develops software based on visual intelligence and only three days ago, I’ve upgraded our software to the latest release at one of our customer’s sites. Although many of our other customers have been working with this version for quite some time now, without any troubles, this customer does have significant performance issues since the upgrade. SQL Server 2017 shows suspended tasks, although plenty resources are available - cpu and memory load are low, only one user is working with the program. He can work with the program for a couple of minutes, then all of a sudden the system lets him wait for a while and then he can continue. During this waiting time, the suspended tasks appear in sql Server. The previous version of our software ran smoothly.
Last month I upgraded sql Server from 2012 to 2017 and windows 2008 to 2012.

I know the information here is pretty basic, but does anyone have any idea how to finetune SQL Server or can anyone tell me what I’m missing? As said, other locations don’t have any problems. A lot of disk IO and suspended tasks, although very few users are working on the application.

Please help...!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by moving the tempdb files to an SSD.